# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.myapp.ui.MyClass

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, classcastexception

I am new to android developing and I encountered a problem which I can't solve.
I implemented an `ExpandableListView` with a custom `Adapter`. I have 5 groups and each group has 1 child item. Each group element is of data type: `org.myapp.ui.MyClass`.

I'm now trying to get the `MyClass` Object of each group element when expanding it. For that I use the `setOnGroupExpandListener`:

```
 lv.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() { 
    public void onGroupExpand (int groupPosition){

      MyClass selected = (MyClass)lv.getAdapter().getItem(groupPosition);
      servId = selected.getServiceId();

      // Do more stuff here
}
});
```

When I now test this code in the emulator, i get the following `ClassCastException`, but only after expanding some groups in the `ExpandableListView` a few times. So for a few times it works and then suddenly it doesn't and i get this exception.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.myapp.ui.MyClass

in this code line

> MyClass selected = (MyClass)lv.getAdapter().getItem(groupPosition);

If anyone has an idea why this happens (but only after expanding a few groups in the `ExpandableListView`), please let me know.

Comment: You're casting a String object to a 'MyClass' object - these types are incompatiable - getItem will get the text (String) from the adapter position.

Comment: but it works for about 10 times before it crashes, so i expand the groups of the exlistiew for a couple of times and it works for these times.

Comment: do you know another way of getting the object of each group item when expanding it?

Comment: solved it myself with this: 

MyClass selected = (MyClass) lv.getExpandableListAdapter().getGroup(groupPosition);

Comment: Glad to hear .. Always the most satisfying way to solve a  problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Taken from oracle docs, ClassCastException Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance. For example, the following code generates a ClassCastException:

```
 Object x = new Integer(0);
 System.out.println((String)x);
```

In your case you are trying to convert a string to a custom class which will never pass because the line `lv.getAdapter().getItem(groupPosition)` gives String instead of MyClass Object.

Comment: But why does it work for a couple of times and then all of a sudden it crashes? That is what is confusing me.

Comment: It never works..as long as your method returning String

Comment: do you know if there is another way to get the object of each group item when expanding it? so what i want is to get the object of the group item which i am expanding.